# how to store only specific element text into input hidden value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to put text value into input hidden value when click on the submit button,

this is I tried so far,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(this).click(function(e){
        var domain_price = $('.domain_price').text();
        $('#order_domain').val(domain_price);
    });
});
```

but this put text from all `.domain_price` content.

**HTML**

this is the result where the `hidden value` is shown. I don't want like this.

I just want to put the only current form value in the hidden value.

```
<h2 style="color:green;">Domain Domain.org is available. <span class="domain_price">$9.95/year</span> <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
                        <input type="hidden" value="$9.95/year$9.95/year" id="order_domain" name="order_domain">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Order Now">
                    </form></h2>


<h2 style="color:green;">Domain Domain.org is available. <span class="domain_price">$9.95/year</span> <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
                        <input type="hidden" value="" id="order_domain" name="order_domain">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Order Now">
                    </form></h2>
```

any Idea how to do this?

Comment: You have duplicate ID values, which is invalid. Also, you're running the function on click anywhere in the document.

Comment: so what should I do? to only get like this `<input type="hidden" value="$9.95/year" id="order_domain" name="order_domain">` ?

Comment: Give the elements unique IDs, and go this way: `$('.domain_price').click(function(e){ $('#order_domain').val($(this).text())});`

Comment: Why are you nesting so much stuff within a `h2`?

Comment: Also, why do you need 2 `forms`?

Comment: its generated through php.

Comment: I need form to post the `#order_domain` value into the php

Comment: This is one way of doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/L89421js/

Comment: @MelanciaUK please post your answer which one you showed me in your fiddle, so I can accept your answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a few issues both with your HTML markup and your Javascript code.

1. Always make sure the elements in a page have unique IDs.
2. Use classes when you want to "group" elements. It makes it easier to select them with a jQuery selector (I'm mentioning the library because you're already using it).

A quick workaround with the HTML:

```
<!-- I can't see why you would need more than 1 form 
     in this page. -->
<!-- You can put the other one back if it's required. -->
<form action="" method="post">
    <!-- You could move this inline style to a proper 
         CSS stylesheet. -->
    <h2 style="color:green;">
        Domain Domain.org is available.
        <!-- Using shared classes to common elements instead of 
             relying on an ID. -->
        <!-- Obviously you can set individual IDs if necessary. -->
        <span class="domain_price">$9.95/year</span>
        <input type="text" class="order_domain" />
        <input type="submit" value="Order Now" />
    </h2>
    <h2 style="color:green;">
        Domain Domain.org is available.
        <span class="domain_price">$9.95/year</span>
        <input type="text" class="order_domain" />
        <input type="submit" value="Order Now" />
    </h2>
</form>
```

And now, the Javascript (jQuery):

```
// Same as document ready, just shorter.
$(function() {
    // When any submit input is clicked.
    $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
        // As this is not a regular button being handled, the default
        // action would be to submit the form it's contained into.
        // We want to stop this so we can set the hidden inputs values.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Using .parents(selector) you can reach this element parent that
        // matches the selector condition.
        // The span you're looking for is within this parent, so we use
        // .children(selector).
        // .text() explains itself.
        var domain_price = $(this).parents('h2').children('.domain_price').text(); 

        // Now we're looking for the hidden input, which is right before the
        // submit input, so we can use .siblings(selector) to grab it.
        // .val() explains itself.       
        $(this).siblings('.order_domain').val(domain_price);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L89421js/1/)

[jQuery .parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

[jQuery .children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

[jQuery .siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)